# Code logic error when using loop to join multiple dataframes

Tags: r, loops

I want to join multiple dataframes while using a loop. But i face an issue, as I need to concatenate numbers to make an intermediate dataframe. It is taking a string as a value, but does not recognising it as a dataframe

Rand_data[] is a quite big dataframe

```
anom_1 <- Rand_data[]
num=c(2:4)
for (n in num)
    {
     d <-  cat(anom_,n)
     d <- cat(anom_,n-1)[sample(nrow(cat(anom_,n-1))),]
     cat(anom_,f) <- rbind(cat(anom_,n-1),cat(anom_,n))
    }
```

cat(anom_,n-1) this is not recognise as a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to a dataframe, you need to change the variable name. `cat` doesn't change the variable name, it just prints out the concatenation. It's better to use `paste` instead:

```
df.names <- paste("anom_", 2:4, sep = "")
```